# Python open and read multiple url txt files

Tags: python

I have this code below and only the contents of file links.txt are being read,,,, the second file (links2.txt) is treated as non-existent by python... how do I read the urls in the 2 files...

```
for i in range(50):
with open("links.txt") as f1, open("links2.txt") as f2:
    urls1 = f1.readlines()
    urls2 = f2.readlines()
    random_urls1 = random.sample(urls1, 5)
    random_urls2 = random.sample(urls2, 5)
    for url in random_urls1:
        driver.get(url.strip())
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            cors1()
        except:
            continue

    for url in random_urls2:
        driver.get(url.strip())
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            cors2()
        except:
            continue
```

What am I missing in the code? Thanks

Comment: Is the second file empty?

Comment: No, it contains url too just like the first file

Comment: What do you mean "the second file is treated as non-existent"?  What happens exactly?

Comment: Have you tried printing `random_urls2` before the second loop? Does it get there? What's its value at that point?

Comment: The code looks completely fine. It is not reproducible without more info.

Comment: Only urls from file 1 is read... the urls from the file 2 is not read

Comment: When taking your code, adding the required imports, stubbing `cors1()` and `cors2()`, creating two files with appropriate names and filling them with valid URLs, this code works just fine. The problem is either with the rest of your program, with the contents of your files, or somewhere else in a part of your setup that you're not sharing. Also, you're saying the URLs are not read - but you provide no evidence of how you arrived at that conclusion? Are they even there? How do you know they're not read? Did you print the list? Check with a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is producing the error that you think it is. I took most of your code and replaced most of the for loop with a `print(url)` and populated my own files with mostly random words. I'm able to see values from both files coming in. So is it possible you're seeing the same values in both files but thinking only one is read? Can you verify any of the records as coming from one file vs the other, say by adding the file name to a `print(url)`?

```
import random

with open("links.txt") as f1, open("links2.txt") as f2:
    urls1 = f1.readlines()
    urls2 = f2.readlines()
    random_urls1 = random.sample(urls1, 5)
    random_urls2 = random.sample(urls2, 5)
    for url in random_urls1:
        print(url)

    for url in random_urls2:
        print(url)
```

Below are the results I produced along with the source file values I used. Not urls but I wanted to simplify to see if I could reproduce the issue.

```
results

tony
hulk
taken
stark
christian
py
hahaha
hard
ulo
welp
```

```
links.txt

blah
taken
liam
neeson
bale
christian
tony
stark
avenger
hulk
```

```
links2.txt

blah2
hard
soft
lambdra
hello
py
hahaha
welp
ulo
yolo
text
```